# nutch-solr: Formatting date from web page metadata into correct Solr format

Tags: datetime, solr, date-format, nutch, date-formatting

I am currently configuring nutch and solr to index web pages and their metadata.
There are metadata tags containing dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd, hence they miss the required time format extension to work as a solr.DateField or solr.TrieDateField.
I would like to use date ranges on the date fields, does not work without having them in one of these formats, right?

Currently my dates are included as text in the schema:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
... 
<field name="Date Modified" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Whenever I use this for the field definition instead...

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<field name="Date Modified" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

...I receive this error message:

```
2012-05-02 23:45:58,370 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0029
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=http://ec.gc.ca/] Error adding field     'Date Modified'='2011-12-05'

ERROR: [doc=http://ec.gc.ca/] Error adding field 'Date Modified'='2011-12-05'

request: http://localhost:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at     org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at     org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java    :244)
    at     org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.j    ava:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:49)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:93)
    at     org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2012-05-02 23:45:58,966 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

I browsed through different forums, but did not find a solution that worked. It might be I missed something about Data Import Handling.
Do I need to change something in the nutch configuration to get the date fields in the right format?

Thanks a lot!

All the best

Comment: I think you meant the second field definition as date fieldType, while you have a string, which is the same as the first definition.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`DateField` docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html). It contains some examples of the correct format for date. This should be ok: `2011-12-05T00:00:00Z`. Don't forget to convert the date to UTC before sending it to Solr.

But your problem is more how to tell nutch to index this field as date converting it to the right format. I had a look at the source code but I haven't found a way out of the box. I guess you should write some code, probably extend the plugin you're using, maybe you could even contribute it back to the project.

Comment: javanna, thanks! I looked at this document and know the correct format, but I do not know how to format my field in this way. I do not have any influence on the date format in the web pages I index. Where in the process from fetching it with nutch, mapping it to solr and the schema definition including request handlers can I adjust the format yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ? Thanks!

Comment: @qlumbus Good point! May I ask how you tell nutch to use those specific metadata? Is it only configuration?

Comment: @javenna In nutch-site.xml I use the index-metatags plugin and specify the meta tags to extract, e.g. `<property>
 <name>metatags.names</name>
<value>Date Modified</value>
</property>`

Comment: I converted it to a trailing Z format by using new Date().toISOString() and SOLR seems to accept this.